# CMake Organization For Dynamic Library With Multiple Classes

Tags: c++, cmake

I am working on a project, where a dynamic library loads a series of related classes.  These classes may rely on similar utility classes, but are generally used interdependently.  My current structure is:

```
MainLibraryDirectory/
    CMakeLists.txt
    mainlibrary.cpp //Provides access to underlying classes
    mainlibrary.h
    /Class1/
        CMakeLists.txt
        class1.cpp
        class1.h
    /Class2/
        CMakeLists.txt
        class2.cpp
        class2.h
```

My Question relates to the Class1 and Class2 `CMakeLists.txt`.  My current approach has been to setup three variables in the main cmake, then:

```
set(my_sources ${my_sources} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/class1.cpp PARENT_SCOPE)
set(my_headers ${my_headers} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/class1.h PARENT_SCOPE)
set(required_libraries ${required_libraries} boost_bla)
```

Is there a better way to do this?  More specifically, I would like to be able to use functions like `include_directory` in the lowlying `CMakeLists.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build Class1 and Class2 into separate static libraries, and then link them together into main library.

Something like this:

```
# Class1/CMakeLists.txt
project(class1)
add_library(class1 STATIC class1.cpp class1.h)

# Class2/CMakeLists.txt
project(class2)
add_library(class2 STATIC class2.cpp class2.h)

# CMakeLists.txt
project(mainlibrary)
add_subdirectory(Class1)
add_subdirectory(Class2)
add_library(mainlibrary SHARED mainlibrary.h mainlibrary.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mainlibrary class1 class2)
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing that as well... It's kind of "hack" since I can't simply compile in one CMake and link in the other...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? With this setup you simple compile mainlibrary, and it's dependencies Class1 and Class2 will be compiled as well.